# Is it correct to write $ \begin{cases} f(x), & \text{if $x \le d$} \\ \infty, & \text{if $x \gt d$} \end{cases}$ as $f(x) + \infty(x \gt d)$?

Tags: inequality, notation, step-function

I'm reading a book on algorithms and I see they wrote the following step function to minimize the function $f(x)$, where the values of $x$ are infeasible if they are greater than $d$.

$$f_{\infty-step} =
\begin{cases}
f(x),  & \text{if $x \le d$} \\
\infty, & \text{if $x \gt d$}
\end{cases}$$

as $$ = f(x) + \infty(x \gt d)$$

Where I assume that the result of $(x \gt d)$ is $0$ or $1$, because they want to minimize the function $f(x)$ wrt $x$. But as far as I know, $\infty$ times $0$ is undefined. So is it correct to write it like this ? If yes, why so?

Comment: Note that in one place you use $+$, in one place you use $\times$.

Comment: @Andrei I meant infinity times zero.

Comment: Yes, but in the title and in the equation above you use plus. Plus woks, as long as $f(x)$ is not $-\infty$. $\times$ woks **only** if $f(x)>0$, so you don't get an indeterminate form. For negative values you would get an absolute minimum.

Comment: maybe I don't understand you correctly, but when $(x>d)$ is true and thus $=1$, then both equations give back infinity, but when $(x\gt d)$ is not true and thus $=0$, then $f(x) + \infty(x \gt d)$ is undefined, while the step function gives back $f(x)$. right?

Comment: In the context of extended real numbers, one sometimes (not always) defines $0\cdot\infty=0$. Given what you write I suppose this is what the authors of the book defined. See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line#Arithmetic_operations

Comment: In this context $\infty(x>d)$ is a function, not a product. It is $\infty$ when $x>d$ and $0$ when $x<d$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of times when dealing with the extended real numbers $\mathbb{\overline R}:=\mathbb{R}\cup\{-\infty,\infty\}$ one defines

$$0\cdot \infty = 0.$$

Remember that $\infty$ in this context is just a formal symbol that we define to have some properties that we expect from infinity, i.e. it is not a number in the normal sense, and so we are also allowed to define it this way if it helps us. If we want to use your notation now we could then define

$$(x>d) := \chi_{(d,\infty)}(x),$$

where $\chi_A$ is what is often used instead to denote the characteristic function, which is defined so that $\chi_A(x)=1$ if $x\in A$ and $\chi_A(x)=0$ if $x\notin A$. Then, as we usually also define

$$a+\infty=\infty$$

for $a\neq -\infty$ we can write

$$f_{\infty-\mathrm{step}}(x)=f(x)+\infty\cdot(x>d).$$

Keep in mind that this is all quite non-standard however, and a piecewise definition as you also provided would probably be preferable in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

It is nonstandard to write your function this way, because in order to interpret $\infty(x>d)$ we have to *assume* that $0\cdot\infty=0$. This is sometimes assumed, but since it is not a standard axiom of real numbers, it much more straightforward to explicitly define our function (via a [$0$-$\infty$ indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(convex_analysis))  ), so we do not have to add any assumptions/axioms in order for our analysis to hold true.